# Is it possible to expand recycler view stack while drag or swipe?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a stacked recyclerview items, I need to expand the recyclerview items while drag or swipe.

I have tried setOnTouchListener and it is expanding, but after expanded try to swipe or scroll the view it is opening the item.

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {

});
```

I need to expand the view then only need to get click the items.

Answer (score 0):

Hey  according to requirements below code will surely help you just use this 
    class

```
        public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    private View mView;
    private float mToHeight;
    private float mFromHeight;

    private float mToWidth;
    private float mFromWidth;




    public ResizeAnimation(View v, float fromWidth, float fromHeight, float toWidth, float toHeight) {
        mToHeight = toHeight;
        mToWidth = toWidth;
        mFromHeight = fromHeight;
        mFromWidth = fromWidth;
        mView = v;
        setDuration(200);
    }

    public ResizeAnimation(View v, float fromWidth, float fromHeight, float toWidth, float toHeight,int duration) {
        mToHeight = toHeight;
        mToWidth = toWidth;
        mFromHeight = fromHeight;
        mFromWidth = fromWidth;
        mView = v;
        setDuration(duration);
    }



    public ResizeAnimation(View v, float fromWidth, float fromHeight, float toWidth, float toHeight,int duration,int offset) {
        mToHeight = toHeight;
        mToWidth = toWidth;
        mFromHeight = fromHeight;
        mFromWidth = fromWidth;
        mView = v;
        setDuration(duration);
        setStartOffset(offset);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float height = (mToHeight - mFromHeight) * interpolatedTime + mFromHeight;
        float width = (mToWidth - mFromWidth) * interpolatedTime + mFromWidth;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = mView.getLayoutParams();
        p.height = (int) height;
        p.width = (int) width;
        mView.requestLayout();
    }



}
```

and `onClick` of your `view` put the lines of  code

```
 ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(view, view.getWidth(), dpToPx(70) , veiw.getWidth(),dpToPx(100));
            view.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

Where first `view.getWidth()` is actual width and `dpToPx(70)` is the actual height of th view and second `view.getWidth()` width which we want to set on view similary `dpToPx(100)` is the height we want to set.

It will expand your view easily for `reverse` just `interchange` the heights.One thing more I did'nt try it in `ConstraintLayout`.